# Why are the variables in the config file not loading in my jest tests?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, environment-variables

So my config file looks like this:

```js
require('dotenv').config();


const PORT = process.env.REACT_APP_PORT

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
? process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_MONGODB_URI
: process.env.REACT_APP_MONGODB_URI

const SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

module.exports = {
  MONGODB_URI,
  PORT,
  SECRET,
  NODE_ENV
}
```

And the .env variables (accessed by config.variable) get loaded no problem in the entire program.
But when I run jest from the folder where the test is, they don't get loaded and stay undefined.

But when I run jest from the root folder (where package.json is), they get loaded.

Could someone explain why please?

And the next weird part:

If i change my config like this:

```js
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../.env") });

//the rest is the same as before
```

It suddenly works even if I run jest from the folder where the tests are.

Can someone please explain this weird interaction to me?

My file structure looks like this btw

[folder/file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPgjI.png)

Comment: Your `.env` file is on the root, isn't it? I guess the dependency loads the configuration from the root, if you are not on the root you need to specify the path.

Comment: @carlosnufe yes, my .env is in the root. But all the enviromant variables already are loaded into the config.js, and exported from there. So jest has nothing to to with the actual .env file.